# How to set an attribute to be a blank string in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I'd like to use UpdateAttribute to set an attribute to be empty, but Nifi says: 'attribute' validated against " is invalid because 'attribute' cannot be empty.  Is there a way to set an empty attribute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with

**`attribute_name`**

```
${literal("")}
```

***`Example:`***

Now nifi will set attribute value as

`Empty string set`

[image]

Comment: Nice trick.  Thank you

Comment: @DumbNewbie Thank you..! If the answer was helpful, accept the answer :)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Sorry about that, I wanted to verify that it worked before accepting.  Worked like a charm.